# Does mark to market accounting have to be FIFO?

Tags: stocks, options, trading

I am thinking about filling for a mark to market trading account but I do not like FIFO. Is FIFO part of mark to market accounting?

Comment: Is this a tax question? Country should be specified.

Answer (score 2):

FIFO or LIFO or by-lot has no impact or consequences if you use mark-to-market - *all* your investments are treated as fully “sold” as of Dec/31 for tax considerations.
It wouldn’t matter in which sequence you sell if you sell *all* of them.

Comment: There’s no restriction on the date at which one is allowed to mark to market.